# If Statement Giving Wrong Output Issue Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, if-condition

I have this simple if statement where there are two columns.

1. Column 1 = Score
2. Column 2 = Test

This is the If Statement Code:

```
=IF([Score]>70,"A","F")
```

If the score is greater than 70 it should give an A in the Test Column. 
If it's less than 70 it's F.

The picture below is the issue.

Am I doing something wrong here?

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of Score field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue on my end if the column "Score" is a single line of text column.

Solution 1: change the type of column "Score" to number instead of single line of text.

Solution 2: add quotes to the number 70 in your formula, like this: `=IF([Score]>"70","A","F")`

Comment: Oh cool thanks for the help. It works now. Does this always happen if your column is a single line of text but the value is a number?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If my answer is helpful to you, please accept it.